# error TS2322: Type 'PropUser | null' is not assignable to type 'PropUser'

Tags: angular, typescript, typescript-typings

Error:

```
Error: src/app/user/containers/shell-user-profile/shell-user-profile.component.html:1:20 - error TS2322: Type 'PropUser | null' is not assignable to type 'PropUser'.
      Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'PropUser'.
    
    1 <app-user-profile [userProfile]="(userProfile$|async)"></app-user-profile>
```

ts file :

```
import { Component, OnInit, Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';
import { actionGetProfile } from "./../../store/actions";
import { selectProfile } from "./../../store/selectors";
import { select, Store } from "@ngrx/store";
import { PropUser } from '../../store/reducer';
import { Observable, pipe } from 'rxjs';
import { map } from "rxjs/operators";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-shell-user-profile',
  templateUrl: './shell-user-profile.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./shell-user-profile.component.scss']
})
export class ShellUserProfileComponent implements OnInit {

  @Output() userProfile$: Observable<PropUser> = new EventEmitter();

  constructor(private readonly store: Store) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.store.dispatch(actionGetProfile());
    this.userProfile$ = this.store.select(selectProfile).pipe(map((data: PropUser) => data));
  }

}
```

html :

```
<app-user-profile [userProfile]="{{userProfile$|async}}"></app-user-profile>
```

What am I missing here? any one help me?

Child ts:

```
import { Component, Input, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { PropUser } from '../../store/reducer';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-user-profile',
  templateUrl: './user-profile.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./user-profile.component.scss']
})
export class UserProfileComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() userProfile: PropUser;

  constructor() {
    this.userProfile = { userId: 0, id: 0, title: "", body: "" }
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

}
```

html:

```
<p>{{userProfile.userId}}</p>
```

Comment: Try `@Input() userProfile!: PropUser;`

Comment: can u add your html code, i get the same issue sometimes. especially with ```ngrx``` observables coming from the store selector. the observable you are passing in as the input is possibly null...

Comment: @ash.io - yes, that's what the issue. i have added the html

Comment: @user2024080 can you try Alireza_Ahmadi 's answer...I think it will work for me and you...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `async` pipes return signature is something like `<T>(input$: Observable<T>): T | null`. Because it returns null to the template while it's awaiting a response from an asynchronous call.

You have multiple option to solve the problem:

```
[userProfile]="(userProfile$|async)!"
```

Or use `$any` like this:

```
 [userProfile]="$any(userProfile$|async)"
```

Comment: This is amazing, would you mind providing a link that explains what ```$any``` is or the ```!``` is

Comment: Yes, works. do not we have solution in ts file level?

Comment: @ash.io `$any` only disable type checking

Comment: @user2024080 how about this : `@Input() userProfile: PropUser | null`?;

Comment: when i visit the page by routing value is not shows, but refresh the page gets it.. what is the issue then?

Comment: @user2024080 I think this is completely different question and I need to know more detail about that. please accept this and ask another question about routing with some more detail

Comment: Accepted. this is nothing to visiting to child component on click of user profile